# Spring data and MongoDB - bidirectional connection of documents

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have two Documents in my Spring data - MongoDB application: 
The first one is Contact and looks like this:

```
public class Contact {

   ...
   private List<Account> accounts;
```

and the second one is Account and looks like this:

```
public class Account {

    ...
    private Contact contact;
```

My question now is, whether there is a better way of:

```
1. create contact object
2. save contact object into database
3. create account object
4. set contact object into account object
5. save account object into database
6. set created account object into contact object
7. update contact object
```

These are many steps and I will avoid to do such a long list to get Contact and Account connected bidirectional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach

MongoDB is a NOSQL DB and hence there is no need of an order to be preserved, such as create and store contact object and then do so more in a sequential way.

Maintain a sequence for Contact and Account object. Before storing these two records get the next number in the sequence and insert the Contact and Account documents.

**References for autoincrement sequence**

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm

Pseudo Code:

```
Get the next Sequence of Contact and Account Id
Add the id's to respective documents
Insert the Documents in Mongodb
```

While retrieving the records you can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) which is a left outer join.

Please note that chance of loss of integrity in data can happen if one insert is happened successfully and other insert did not happen for some reason.
We dont have transaction support in Mongodb across collections, [more info](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/write-operations-atomicity/).